# Error when installing Tensorflow with Conda on Windows

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda

Operating on Windows 10.

I am trying to install Tensorflow within a conda environment. The Anaconda 3 version I am using is the one that can be installed from within Visual Studio, conda version number is 4.6.14.

I created a new environment with `conda create -n test python=3.6` and afterwards tried to install Tensorflow:

```
> conda activate test
> (test) conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

after which I'm getting the following error:

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
tensorflow-base-1.13 | 217.6 MB  | ############################################################################ | 100%
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Anaconda3_64\\pkgs\\tensorflow-base-1.13.1-gpu_py36h871c8ca_0\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\eigen_archive\\unsupported\\Eigen\\src\\SpecialFunctions\\SpecialFunctionsPacketMath.h'
```

Any idea on what could be the error here?

Edit: `conda info` returned:

```
active environment : base
active env location : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64
shell level : 1
user config file : C:\Users\Me\.condarc
populated config files :
conda version : 4.6.14
conda-build version : 3.10.5
python version : 3.6.5.final.0
base environment : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64  (writable)
channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
package cache : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs
                C:\Users\Me\.conda\pkgs
                C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
envs directories : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\envs
                   C:\Users\Me\.conda\envs
                   C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs                                                               platform : win-64
user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
administrator : True                                                                                                       netrc file : None
offline mode : False
```

Comment: Has this happened repeatedly or just one try? I checked the tarball and that file is in there, so it should be in your install. Perhaps something with the install location? Please add the output of `conda info` to your question.  Also, you may want to try `conda install -vv tensorflow-gpu` to see if the debug info provides any insight.

Comment: Added the results from conda info in the original post.
This error happened repeatedly and always when installing tensorflow-base, no matter if the command was `conda install tensorflow`, `conda install tensorflow-gpu`, `conda install keras` etc.
It also happens in a completely fresh conda environment, where nothing else (except python 3.6) is installed.
I managed to install tensorflow in my environment with `pip install tensorflow-gpu` though, but I think it'd still be interesting to know why it doesn't work with conda.

Comment: That is a hell of a long path for the install location.  I know that previous versions of versions of conda had issues with having a space in the installation path.  They migrated the install location on windows to C:\Anaconda (for all-user installs) to avoid this issue.  You may want to try try installing a different build of tensorflow to see if a bad build slipped by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. Like you, I also did the convenient "mistake" of installing Anaconda with the Visual Studio installer. As James pointed out, the problem is indeed that the file path is too long (> 260). Anyway, it would seem we have to swallow the bitter pill, uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it at root level (I'll go for Mini-Conda this time).

Before I do that, I'll try to find a way of moving the Anaconda3_64\pkgs\ to a different location. Should that work, I'll post it here.

**Edit: Got the solution, no reinstall necessary!**
The problem comes from windows itself, which by default does not support long file paths. But this can be changed using a registry flag:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/The-Windows-10-default-path-length-limitation-MAX-PATH-is-256-characters.html

1. Open Regedit as Admin
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
3. Change  LongPathsEnabled to 1 (DWORD 32 bit)

**Warning:** it could break compatibility of older programs. So far, for me everything is still working fine. If you should run into problems, simply revert the setting (and remember you have changed this setting!)